# using sum and ifnull conditions inside named scope

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have the following named scope in the 'Book' model

```
named_scope :batch_book_status_55, lambda { |batch_id| {
:select => "ifnull( sum( if( BK_DB_STATUS_FK = 55, 1, 0 ) ), 0) as ASSIGNED",
:conditions => ["BK_BATCH = ?", batch_id]
}}



<%  Book.batch_book_status_55(batch.BATCH_ID).each_with_index do |book, index| %>
  <% if book.ASSIGNED.to_i != 0%>
  Assigned : <%= book.ASSIGNED %> 
  <% end %>
<% end %
```

The code below display the number of books in a particular batch with status = 55 (BK_DB_STATUS_FK = 55).

I am a bit confused with the named scope code. I would appreciate it if someone can please explain the code to me.

Answer (score 1):

You might be better off using a `self` method here instead of a named scope. Please refer: http://www.railway.at/2010/03/09/named-scopes-are-dead/